# Изменить выпадающий список combobox javafx

Tags: javafx

В combobox будет два значения либо Организация, либо Филиал. Организация стоит по умолчанию. Как сделать так, что-бы выпадал только один элемент, а если его выбрали, то в выпадающем списке он заменялся на второй.

```
 ComboBox cm = new ComboBox();
 cm.setPromptText("Организация");
 cm.getItems().addAll("Филиал");
```

Как сделать, чтобы при выборе Филиал, он заменялся на Организация.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // При явной установке значения, поле value может содержать данные не находящиеся в items
        // При выборе значения через UI оно связывается с конкретным элементом списка (selectionModel)
        final ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        // Флаг для отделения действий слушателя от прочих (предотвращение зацикливания)
        final AtomicBoolean userAction = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        comboBox.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            // Если значение устанавливается не этим слушателем
            if ( userAction.compareAndSet(true, false) ) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    // Возвращаем ранее выбранный элемент в список (для возможности повторного выбора)
                    if ( oldValue != null ) comboBox.getItems().add(oldValue);
                    if ( newValue != null ) {
                        // Убираем выбранный элемент из списка (что бы не отображался)
                        comboBox.getItems().remove(newValue);
                        // устанавливаем значение не связанное со списком
                        comboBox.setValue(newValue);
                    }
                    // Отмечаем завершение работы слушателя
                    userAction.lazySet(true);
                });
            }
        });

        comboBox.getItems().addAll("Организация", "Филиал", "Test", "Test1");

        comboBox.setValue("Организация"); // Установка значения по умолчанию не обязательна

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(comboBox, 200, 40));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще Ваш вопрос довольно спорный в плане юзабилити. Не уверен, что данное поведение интерфейса будет действительно кардинально облегчать жизнь. При этом самим ComboBox такое поведение по-умолчанию не предусмотрено. Там суть в том, что вы в список вариантов добавляете объекты и выбираете из ВСЕГО списка. Соответственно придется делать костыль, что не есть хорошо.

Также советую вместо `ComboBox` использовать `ChooseBox`, т.к. ИМХО выходит нагляднее.

Answer (score 0):

Я могу быть не прав, но разве "PromptText" - не подсказка?

```
->
setPromptText("Животные");
getItems().addAll("Собак","Котейка","Порось","Птиц");
```

Comment: Я бы ещё "Кенгур" добавил.

Comment: "Долфин" и "Змей"